# Cannot protect a translated page in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have a MediaWiki site.

On one page I have a form which is implemented by the [EmailForm](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailForm) extension.

The page must be protected before it will function.  I also need to translate this page into Czech.

So I have installed the [Language Extension Bundle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle) and then used the translate extension to mark the page for translation.

I have also translated the page.  The original page works but the Czech translated page does not work because it is not protected.

I attempted to protect the `/cs` page but I received this error message:

> You do not have permission to change protection levels for this page the following reasons:

```
- This page cannot be updated manually. This page is a translation of the page [Green Card Request] and the translation can be updated using the translation tool.
- You cannot change the protection levels of this page because you do not have permission to edit it.
```

I am a site admin.

For the time being I have disabled the code that implements the protection requirement, but this is not a good long term solution.

```
/*
if ( !($wgTitle->isProtected ('edit')) )
    return ( EMAILFORM_NAME . " is only active on protected pages." );
*/
```

Comment: Probably because this question is not about programming, but about maintaining a MediaWiki site, and hence off topic here

Comment: Where should I ask this question then?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a suitable Stack Exchange site. MediaWiki seems to have a forum: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confident that all translated pages are safe to use as e-mail forms, you could change the code you quoted to:

```php
if ( !($wgTitle->isProtected('edit')) &&
     !(TranslatablePage::isTranslationPage($wgTitle)) ) {
    return ( EMAILFORM_NAME . " is only active on protected pages." );
}
```

Of course, if you don't necessarily trust the content of all translated pages, then things get more complicated.  Basically, you'd have to figure out which pages you *do* consider safe enough, and modify the check accordingly.  Alas, I'm not really familiar enough with the Translate extension to tell how its privileges model works, so I can't give any concrete suggestions here.

(Also, of course, you'll need to reapply this change every time you upgrade the EmailForm extension, but that's the case with your current temporary fix too.  A useful way to maintain such customizations is to keep a (unified) [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) of all the changes you've made, and reapply it with [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) after every upgrade.  If you like, you can also use git to maintain a local branch of MediaWiki with your customizations, and merge in changes from upstream whenever a new version is released.)

---

Ultimately, I suspect that the proper way to handle this would be to fix the Translate extension to let translation target pages be protected in the normal way.  There's a whitelist of allowed actions in the PageTranslationHooks::preventDirectEditing() method, but I suspect that it might not be as simple as adding `protect` to that list, because:

1. IIRC, MediaWiki itself may very likely assume that you must be able to edit a page in order to protect it, and
2. if you did manage to protect the page, this might (or might not) trigger some weird behavior in the Translate extension.

Still, it should be possible to work around these issues, one way or another.  Even if you don't feel like trying to do it yourself, you might want to [file a feature request](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/create/?projects=MediaWiki-extensions-Translate) about it (assuming someone hasn't done that already, of course).